# How to display a div and its contents reflected in IE 8 or above?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I want to render a div backward, and then render the table cells inside it forward. I prepared a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/djsvL/3/ which works in my browser (chrome).

However, it doesn't work in IE 8. From what I've seen so far, I can flip the text or image within a div or cell, but I can't seem to flip the entire layout (for instance, notice how the table cells are reversed).

Is a trick like this possible using IE8's `filter:fliph` ? If so, what am I doing wrong or how can I do this?

**Edit:** Here is a screenshot of what I see in IE8: http://tinypic.com/r/2e4yw3p/6

Comment: Well. I have IE10 but if there I set IE8 mode then all works fine like on Chrome. Can you show screen from your IE8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to set a background color.

IE does not handle transparency well, it uses black instead of transparent, and the box technically has a transparent background.